# Decrease in available memory on host and seeing large amount of unreachable objects from heap dump

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

My java service is running on a 16 GB RAM host with `-Xms and -Xmx` set to 8GB. The host is running a few other processes.

I noticed that my service consuming more memory over time. I ran this command `ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n` on the host and recorded the memory usage by my java service. When the service started, it used about 8GB memory (as `-Xms and -Xmx` set to 8GB) but after a week, it used about 9GB+ memory. It consumed about 100MB more memory per day.

I compared heap dumps and didn't find any memory leaks. There are not much difference in the heap memory usage before/after restart my java service. However, I noticed that quite large amount of unreachable objects. I compared two heap dump and seeing about 500MB increase in retained heap size due to unrechable objects.

So my guess is some of objects are in young spaces are not GCed or moved to old space and not GCed because full GC hasn't kicked in.

My question is

1. Is my JVM config correct? Do I need to make change to avoid large amount of unreachable objects.

```
-Xms8G -Xmx8G
-XX:+UseG1GC 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=75 
-XX:MetaspaceSize=128m 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
-XX:+CITime 
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
-XX:+PrintGCCause
-XX:+PrintJNIGCStalls
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=2
```

2. From `jmap -heap` shown below, I see that `MaxNewSize` is set to 4GB while `NewSize` set to 1MB. Could it cause any issues in GC that leave large amount of unreachable objects? Some of settings were blindly set (from some default values).

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 8589934592 (8192.0MB)*
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 5150605312 (4912.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 134217728 (128.0MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1065353216 (1016.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 4194304 (4.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 2048
   capacity = 8589934592 (8192.0MB)
   used     = 2241515408 (2137.6756744384766MB)
   free     = 6348419184 (6054.324325561523MB)
   26.09467376023531% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 26
   capacity = 4655677440 (4440.0MB)
   used     = 109051904 (104.0MB)
   free     = 4546625536 (4336.0MB)
   2.3423423423423424% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 35
   capacity = 146800640 (140.0MB)
   used     = 146800640 (140.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 480
   capacity = 3787456512 (3612.0MB)
   used     = 1981468560 (1889.6756744384766MB)
   free     = 1805987952 (1722.3243255615234MB)
   52.31660228234985% used
```

Comment: If you have no valid explaination for an increasing demand for memory (an ever growing database would be a valid explaination), your application has probably a memory leak in 9 of 10 cases. One other error might be a bug within the JVM or an hardware bug (very unlikely). I suggest wait until your application crashes and read the error log ^^ PS you may try to enforce a crash.

Comment: That's something I am trying to figure out from the heap dump, it's clear that there are no leaks but if unreachable objects are increasing over time. I saw other posting about native java memory leak that's not shown in the heap dump. I am also looking into that but like to see if there are anything odd in my jvm configs.

Comment: Normally, Java doesn't produce an ordinary "memory leak". An ordinary "memory leak" is only possible due malfunction of the JVM or malfunction of the hardware. It's more likely that some part of your code produces more and more objects, which are never used again. At some point the garbage collector might turn in and remove those unused objects. But there might be objects which can't be garbage collected, and those objects are "producing" a behaviour which looks like a "memory leak", which has nearly the same effects. Take a look here: https://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.outOfMemory

Comment: PS you might try to use another JVM or another real machine and see if the problem is persistent. But I really don't think it's a problem of the JVM or of your real machine. (Maybe if you use old buggy versions.)

Comment: I you can’t answer that question from all those details in you GC log files, I wonder why you waste resources in creating those detailed logs.

Comment: Do you actually get an OOM?

Comment: No, I didn't get OOM. @Holger what do you mean? can you be more specific which GC log I can take a look to find the issue?

Comment: The question, how it is currently written, states 3 different problems: 1) growth of the process' memory footprint; 2) usage of JVM options; 3) unreachable objects in the heap dump. Please, don't ask multiple questions in one.

Comment: What do you mean when you say “which GC log”? How many does your JVM create? The majority of the posted JVM options are dedicated to GC logging. Apparently, you like to tell the JVM “log as much as you can” but do not even consider looking into the result (or post it with your question)…

Comment: @Holger there is 1 GC file. Can you tell me what to look at to find reasons of large amount of unreachable objects? I used GCPlot and noticed promotion rate is higher than allocation rate, would that be a problem? I see NewSize is set to 1.29MB where as MaxNewSize set to 5GB. Should I set both to 4/5GB? My service turned off `DisableExplicitGC `, would that be a problem?

Comment: You have configured `MaxGCPauseMillis=75`, so you may check whether the pauses are in that order of magnitude, so the GC does not reclaim more memory to keep this pause time goal. That wouldn't be a problem, those objects still can be reclaimed at a later GC cycle. In the worst case, it'll do a Full GC before running out of memory.